# Unable to run Jar file on other computer. Error: no file in java.library.path

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have got the SDK for a particular project. I have installed this SDK on my computer and then I have made some modifications to the sample code provided by my client. And after that I created the runnable JAR for this code from Eclipse and it runs successfully from both CMD as well as by double clicking on it.

Now I want my Jar file to be executed on others PC but I receive an error : No MorphoSmartSDKJavaWrapper in java.library.path.

I was also getting the same error but then I set the environment variables from system for this but I wanted to remove this dependency of environment variables so I wrote the code in Main Class to setup Environment Variables in memory and now without setting up any environment variables in the system manually I am able to successfully open my Jar file on my PC.

Now I want to run this Jar file on other PC  but it gives me an error of "**error : No MorphoSmartSDKJavaWrapper in java.library.path.** "

I am not understanding what I am missing out. Why I am not able to open this JAR file by double click on other PC. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @kuhajeyan your jar is looking for the native library (probably some dll) in the paths set in the *java.library.path* system property. The native library is available in your system after installaion of the SDK and *java.library.path* is pointing to that location where it is available. For the other systems for which you are getting the error, either the native library is not available or the *java.library.path* is not pointing to the location where it is available.

Since your requirement is to run the jar on double click then I'd suggest you to use

```
public static void load(String filename)
```

[api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load(java.lang.String)) of System claas to load the library as the application starts.

For example if your library file name is foo.dll and is located at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin then your method will look like the following:

```
System.load("C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_73\\bin\\foo.dll")
```

Comment: How should I set the path for this then? I saved the native libraries in a single folder and tried to access them from code. To get the common path I saved those libraries in Java bin folder. Yet I am getting the same error.

Comment: See the updated answer. You are not necessarily required to put your libraries in the bin folder of the JDK or JRE. It can be anywhere on the file system.

Comment: I gave the path in Native Library Locations in eclipse under build path, created JAR and tried running it on other computer. Now I am having a new Error : Can't find dependent libraries.

Comment: The native library path in Build Path of eclipse is specific to the eclipse runtime. So, when you export the project as a runnable jar, the native library or the path info in not exported. About the

Comment: cont. About the "Can't find dependent libraries": The error means that the library that you are trying to load in your jar is found on the system but that library has dependency on other libraries which are not available on the path pointed by java.library.path system property. You can use DW (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out the missing dependencies of your native library.

Comment: Thank you @Keshaw.I will try this.

Comment: I used DW and was able to look what all DLL files were missing. I saved all those files in " C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib " and now the Jar opens in other computers. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

it is your application/jar depends on other wrapper library probably a dll( probably installed under program files when you installed the SDK). You need to provide that library when you run this application in other machines. A short cut way is providing it via command line args

```
java -cp xxxx.jar -Djava.library.path=path/to/lib
```

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/

Comment: I tried the link you gave me for java-library-path. I gave the path for Native Library location. After this I created the Jar once again and tried to execute on other PC. still the same error for other PC. Jar running successfully on my PC.

Comment: then other possible cause would be native library that you are running not compatible host machine architecture (x86 / x64)

Comment: When I install the SDK the native libraries are present in below path "E:\Testing\Morpho_24Oct\PC\Demos\x64"

Comment: My real concern is I want my Jar to open on a single click on others PC. I am able to do this on my PC. Now I have copied this JAR on my friend PC but when I try to open this JAR by double clicking on it, it gives me the above Error of  "No MorphoSmartSDKJavaWrapper in java.library.path "